# Laravel passing username parameter to controller from user.blade.php

Tags: php, parameters, laravel, controller

Hi on my website I have profile with username parameter root/user/{username}. I was planning to add button to block the user. My problem is that when other user click block button, the button do stuffs in the Check.php controller but it doesn't pass the user/{username} parameter that I need in if statements. My question is how I can pass the {username} parameter from my user.blade.php to the Check.php controller?

Answer (score 0):

As we are not seeing any code here, it seems that to do what you need, you just have to create a route pointing to your controller method and eventually a route to redirect your users when successufully blocked:

```
Route::get('user/block/{username}', 'BlockUserController@block');

Route::get('userBlocked', 'BlockUserController@blocked');
```

And the controller itself:

```
class BlockUserController extends Controller {

    public function block($username) 
    {
        $user = User::where('username', $username);

        $user->blocked = true;

        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to('userBlocked');
    }

    public function blocked($username) 
    {
        return View::make('user.blocked');
    }

}
```

And then if you click the button pointing to the route:

```
http://application.com/user/block/user3398940
```

It will be blocked.

If you want to go a little more advanced in Laravel, you can use dependency injection and remove some code from your controller:

```
class BlockUserController extends Controller {

    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user) 
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function block($username) 
    {
        if ($user->block($username))
        {
            return Redirect::to('userBlocked');
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'User not found');
    }

    public function blocked($username) 
    {
        return View::make('user.blocked');
    }

}
```

And your user model would have to have a block method:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function block($username) 
    {
        if ($user = $this->newQuery()->where('username', $username))
        {
            $user->blocked = true;

            return $user->save();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```